# Using SUM in Google Sheets with indirect ranges

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need to use `SUM` formula to fill the Total formula until next Total comes in Google Sheets like this:

```
Total   6

A       1

B       2

C       3

Total   15

A       9

B       6
```

Comment: Apologies. It's the first time that I am using some forum to ask an issue. I just need a formula which can add value in A,B,C in first total and then in second total it adds the value again till the next total.

Comment: So why not have `=SUM(…)` of all the cells next to A, B, and C? Or where exactly are you stuck? Your problem is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

- paste in **B1**, **B5**, etc. where you need...

  ```
  =SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1; 2; 4)&":"&ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH("TOTAL"; 
   INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1; 1; 4)&":A"); 0)+ROW()-1; ROWS(A:A)); 1; 4)))
  ```

  [image: 0]